# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass for display on application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get a customized dropdown menu on my app so that each of my `list` instances have their own link on the navigation.  So far here's my `application.html.erb`:

```
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="/lists" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Lists<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "All Lists", lists_path %></li>
              <% @lists.each do |list|%>
                <li><%= link_to list_path(list) do %>
                  <%= list.name %>
                <% end %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

However, I now get an error that says `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` on the line with `@lists.each do |list|`. I know this (or a similar) structure works on another page, so I'm thinking it must have something to do with the controllers.  My `lists_controller` performs this action correctly on my `lists#index` page with these definitions:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @lists = List.all
    @list = List.new
  end
...
```

And I have this in my `application_controller` currently to mirror that:

```
def application
  @lists = List.all
  @list = List.new
end
```

But I'm pretty sure that's not right. What should I have in my `application_controller` to get it to recognize this in my menu on all the pages?

Comment: I don't think you need the `application` method for application controllers. Is there a reason why you need that?

Comment: I tried it without any definition in the application controller and with def index and the same definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be wary of performing the List query each time the a page is rendered on your app and either cache the query or use manual links if at all possible to avoid any performance problems.

That being said...

You have a few options one of which being a `before_action` in your application_controller that sets any instance_variables you would like present.

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_lists

  def set_lists
    @lists = List.all
  end
end
```

You could also add a `dropdown_lists` method to your ApplicationHelper file similar to:

```
def dropdown_lists
  List.all
end
```

which you would use as a replacement to `@lists` in your view similar to: `dropdown_lists.each.....`

Also (as an aside) you probably want to move this header information to a partial to keep your layout file clean, but thats not really part of the answer :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ahhh!  Beautiful!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is wrong here. I believe that you are using `application.html.erb` incorrectly.

`application.html.erb` is for generally for placing html that will be displayed on all of your web pages. Think of a header menu as an example.

For your list, it looks to me like you want to display your links on your `index` action which would be `app/views/list/index.html.erb'.

So I would do this:

- Remove the `def application` method from `application_controller`.
- Create an `index.html.erb` file for app/views/list` directory.
- Now transfer your code in `application.html.erb` to `app/views/list/index.html.erb`

That should do it.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: Use `before_action` to trigger any necessary pre-loading related to layout.

Comment: I know that application.html.erb is for all the pages. I am trying to get a drop down menu that links to all of my lists from anywhere in the app. I already have a lists#index in place. And it is error free, this one is just giving me trouble.